# What's the syntax of clsx to add two classNames when one condition satisfied?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, menubar, classname, clsx

I have a `menu` block, i use `clsx` lib for the `conditional classname` rendering.
I wanna add two `className` at the same line when the condition satisfies. Some one can tell me the right syntax ?
For now i put the two classes into an array, but it doesn't work...

Thank you.

```
export default function Navbar({}){
...
 return (
    <li key={link.label} 
        className={
                 clsx({ 
                    ['stroke-black','text-transparent']: link.label==='HelloAgain',
                  })
    }>
         <Link href='#'>
            {link.label}
         </Link>            
    </li>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have all the classes in a object key in a single string, separated by spaces.

```js
const classes = clsx({
  'stroke-black text-transparent': true,
});

console.log(classes);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/clsx@2.0.0/dist/clsx.min.js"></script>
```